# Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent using array with characters

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to initialize

```
labels =['dh';'Dh';'gj';'Gj';'ll';'Ll';'nj';'Nj';'rr';'Rr';'sh';'Sh';'th';'Th';'xh';'Xh';'zh';'Zh';'ç';'Ç';'ë';'Ë'];
```

But it shows me the error on title.When I try with numbers it's all perfect but not with characters.What could be the problem?

Comment: Is your intention to concatenate them or store them as individual strings and/or characters?

Comment: Can you please select an answer or clarify if you have any issues with either?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to eliminate any padding, you can also store it into a cell as follows.

```
labels = {'dh';'Dh';'gj';'Gj';
         'll';'Ll';'nj';'Nj';
         'rr';'Rr';'sh';'Sh';
         'th';'Th';'xh';'Xh';
         'zh';'Zh';'ç';'Ç';
         'ë';'Ë'};
```

Then you can reference the "i"th element using `labels{i}` instead of `labels(i,:)` which is simpler. You can further run more string operations using `cellfun` and not interfere with any existing values that you've stored.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [krisdestruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29785540/3297440) that using a cell array makes the code accessing the strings simpler and is generally more idiomatic. That is what I would also recommend unless there is a compelling reason to do something else.

For completeness, you could use the `char` function to add the padding automatically for you if you really want a character array:

```
>> char('aa','bb','c')

ans =

aa
bb
c
```

where the last row is `'c '`. From the `char` documentation:

> S = char(A1,...,AN) converts the arrays A1,...,AN into a single character array. After conversion to characters, the input arrays become rows in S. **Each row is automatically padded with blanks as needed**. An empty string becomes a row of blanks.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Epic use of `char` for padding, I learn a new function every day! +1

Answer (score 1):

From the [Mathworks documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html):

> Apply the MATLAB concatenation operator, []. Separate each row with a semicolon (;). **Each row must contain the same number of characters**. For example, combine three strings of equal length:

You can try padding like this to make every row 2 characters:

```
labels = ['dh';'Dh';'gj';'Gj';
         'll';'Ll';'nj';'Nj';
         'rr';'Rr';'sh';'Sh';
         'th';'Th';'xh';'Xh';
         'zh';'Zh';'ç ';'Ç ';
         'ë ';'Ë '];
```